# How to display a template in html file ionic cordova mobile app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I have a template which i need to display in my html file, the content of the template is dynamic sometimes i get some images in it and sometimes some table content.My content to display is like this:

```
> <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" style="width:
> 100%"><tbody><tr><td style="background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
> width: 75%;"><h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:
> rgb(255, 255, 255);">Action Management</span></h1></td><td
> style="text-align: right;"><img alt
> src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/08/13/15/spring-bird-2295431_1280.jpg"
> style=\"width: 228px; height: 89px; float: right;\"
> /></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><p>Help: Click here for <a
> href=\"cceurope/emsimpop.nsf/va_ApprovedOpControls/938DB4DFD3F945B280257E0D0045E851?opendocument\"
> target=\"_blank\">user guide 1</a> | <a
> href=\"cceurope/emsimpop.nsf/va_ApprovedOpControls/9976E08F22A8ED7B00258259004C4E8D?opendocument\"
> target=\"_blank\">user guide 2</a> | <a
> href=\"cceurope/emsimpop.nsf/va_ApprovedOpControls/2081D535C4873C8780257E0D004629AA?opendocument\"
> target=\"_blank\">user guide
> 3</a></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p></p>
```

which looks like this

> > Action Management
> >
> > Help: Click here for user guide 1 | user guide 2 | user guide
> >     3

in .html file how should i add this so that i can view this template in my mobile app.

Comment: please format your html code above

Comment: you should take a look at ionic documentation, look for the responsive grid in ionic